# This declaration has no storage class or type specifier Error

Tags: visual-c++

**Hello Everyone!** I have a Project due tomorrow and I accidently chosen a hard one and now im regretting it. Im trying to make digital voting system on a small scale just to represent my idea as I'm a 2nd semester student of BSCS. I made the entire code by myself. The first code I made was working code but the output was not as I desired. I wanted to change the Vote after casting the vote. But it wasnt changing it. **This is the first code Below:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>


using namespace std;

void VoteLIST();
void VoteReturn();

class NADRA
{
protected:
    double nic[4] = { {42401335},{1},{2},{3} };
    int knum[4] = { {123},{1},{2},{3} };
    int vote[4] = { {0},{0},{0},{0} };
    void voteCHANGE(int a, int b)
    {
        vote[a] = b;
    }
};

class CNIC :protected NADRA
{
private:
    //nic = <=
    double cnic;
    int KhandaanNUM;
public:
    CNIC()
    {
        cnic = KhandaanNUM = 0;
    }
    CNIC(double a, int b)
    {
        cnic = a;
        KhandaanNUM = b;
    }
    void SetDATA(double a, int b)
    {
        cnic = a;
        KhandaanNUM = b;
    }

    double getCNIC()
    {
        return cnic;
    }
    int getKNUM()
    {
        return KhandaanNUM;
    }
    int voteSTATUS = 0;
    bool check()
    {
        for (int loop = 0; loop < 4; loop++)
        {
            if (cnic == nic[loop] && KhandaanNUM == knum[loop] && (vote[loop] == 0))
            {
                voteSTATUS = vote[loop];
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    void setVOTE(int c)
    {
        //vote[voteSTATUS] = c;
        voteCHANGE(voteSTATUS, c);
    }
    void VoteReturn()
    {
        cout << voteSTATUS;
    }
};

class VOTEmenu
{
private:
    CNIC c1;
    double Cnic;
    int kNum;
public:
    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "Enter CNIC: ";
        cin >> Cnic;
        cout << "Enter Khandaan Number: ";
        cin >> kNum;
        c1.SetDATA(Cnic, kNum);
    }
    void checkData()
    {
        if (c1.check() == true)
        {
            int choice;
            system("cls");
            VoteLIST();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Please choose the Respective Party Number" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            c1.setVOTE(choice);
            system("cls");
            cout << "You have successfully voted for Party Number: " << choice <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "You are not Eligible to Cast Vote!" << endl;
            cout << "Reasons:\n1) CNIC or Khandaan Number You entered may be Incorrect";
            cout << "\n2) You may not be 18 Above\n3) You may have already casted the vote";
        }
    }
    void Data2()
    {
        if (c1.check() == true)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Your CNIC Number: " << Cnic << endl;
            cout << "Khandaan Number: " << kNum << endl;
            cout << "You Have Voted for party number: "; c1.VoteReturn();
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "You are not Eligible to Cast Vote!" << endl;
            cout << "Reasons:\n1) CNIC or Khandaan Number You entered may be Incorrect";
            cout << "\n2) You may not be 18 Above\n3) You may have already casted the vote";
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        VOTEmenu v;
        int choice;
        system("cls");
        cout << "Welcome To Vote Menu!" << endl;
        cout << "Please choose any one of the following" << endl;
        cout << "1) Cast Vote\n2) Check Vote";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        v.GetData();
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            v.checkData();
            _getch();
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            v.Data2();
            _getch();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Wrong DATA:" << endl;
        }
        
    }
}

void VoteLIST()
{
    cout << "VOTE LIST" << endl;
    cout << "1: PTI\n2:PMLN\n3:PPP\n4:MQM" << endl;
}
```

**Now I tried to remake the code** and added file stream. taking text from external source instead of making array inside the visual studio and assigning values. but now Im facing an error which says **This declaration has no storage class or type specifier** The code is below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

void VoteLIST();
void VoteReturn();

class NADRA
{
protected:
    fstream Text;
    int nic[2];
    int knum[2];
    int vote[2];
    int count = 0;
    int ccnic = 0;
    int knumm = 0;
    int votee = 0;
    Text.open("Nadra.txt")
    {
        while (!Text.eof())
        {
            Nadra >> ccnic >> knumm >> votee;
            nic[count] = ccnic;
            knum[count] = knumm;
            vote[count] = votee;
            count++;
        }
    }
    Text.close();

    void voteCHANGE(int a, int b)
    {
        vote[a] = b;
    }
};

class CNIC :protected NADRA
{
private:
    //nic = <=
    double cnic;
    int KhandaanNUM;
public:
    CNIC()
    {
        cnic = KhandaanNUM = 0;
    }
    CNIC(double a, int b)
    {
        cnic = a;
        KhandaanNUM = b;
    }
    void SetDATA(double a, int b)
    {
        cnic = a;
        KhandaanNUM = b;
    }

    double getCNIC()
    {
        return cnic;
    }
    int getKNUM()
    {
        return KhandaanNUM;
    }
    int voteSTATUS = 0;
    bool check()
    {
        for (int loop = 0; loop < 4; loop++)
        {
            if (cnic == nic[loop] && KhandaanNUM == knum[loop] && (vote[loop] == 0))
            {
                voteSTATUS = vote[loop];
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    void setVOTE(int c)
    {
        //vote[voteSTATUS] = c;
        voteCHANGE(voteSTATUS, c);
    }
    void VoteReturn()
    {
        cout << voteSTATUS;
    }
};

class VOTEmenu
{
private:
    CNIC c1;
    double Cnic;
    int kNum;
public:
    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "Enter CNIC: ";
        cin >> Cnic;
        cout << "Enter Khandaan Number: ";
        cin >> kNum;
        c1.SetDATA(Cnic, kNum);
    }
    void checkData()
    {
        if (c1.check() == true)
        {
            int choice;
            system("cls");
            VoteLIST();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Please choose the Respective Party Number" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            c1.setVOTE(choice);
            system("cls");
            cout << "You have successfully voted for Party Number: " << choice << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "You are not Eligible to Cast Vote!" << endl;
            cout << "Reasons:\n1) CNIC or Khandaan Number You entered may be Incorrect";
            cout << "\n2) You may not be 18 Above\n3) You may have already casted the vote";
        }
    }
    void Data2()
    {
        if (c1.check() == true)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Your CNIC Number: " << Cnic << endl;
            cout << "Khandaan Number: " << kNum << endl;
            cout << "You Have Voted for party number: "; c1.VoteReturn();
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "You are not Eligible to Cast Vote!" << endl;
            cout << "Reasons:\n1) CNIC or Khandaan Number You entered may be Incorrect";
            cout << "\n2) You may not be 18 Above\n3) You may have already casted the vote";
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        VOTEmenu v;
        int choice;
        system("cls");
        cout << "Welcome To Vote Menu!" << endl;
        cout << "Please choose any one of the following" << endl;
        cout << "1) Cast Vote\n2) Check Vote";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        v.GetData();
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            v.checkData();
            _getch();
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            v.Data2();
            _getch();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Wrong DATA:" << endl;
        }

    }
}

void VoteLIST()
{
    cout << "VOTE LIST" << endl;
    cout << "1: PTI\n2:PMLN\n3:PPP\n4:MQM" << endl;
}
```

**Can Someone please help??? Tomorrow is my last date! I just want my program to take data from text, chech the data with user entered data, IF correct, it will proceed and show for vote menu. if not, It will give error etc.**
I know I'm a very pathetic learner. But You guys are professional! I will learn alot from you. Please help me!

Comment: You have statements (e.g. `Text.open("Nadra.txt")` ) right in the middle of a class definition. Only declarations are allowed there, statements must be in the body of some function. Perhaps you meant to place that code into a constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! The error is solved  ! Now I know why I was getting that ! :)